# GMMap stopped working with Javascript error

Tags: gmlib

The GMMap stopped working in the recent days. Calling DoMap shows the map for a moment and after an empty page displays with the following message:
"Oops! Something went wrong. This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details".

Questions

- any idea what can cause the problem?
- how can I debug javascript console from Delphi?
- the last commit on the github project Cadetill updated readme.md
  with the message 'This project is closed due to the new Google Maps
  license'. What has changed with the licence that the project became closed?

Comment: on Resource folder, you have the map.html file. With this, you can "debug" the javascript error. When you solves the error, recompile resources and library

Comment: Thank you for your response. In the Javascript console I got 2 warnings 'Google Maps JavaScript API warning: RetiredVersion'  and 'Google Maps JavaScript API warning: SensorNotRequired'. I deleted the sensor part from the URL and I tried with versions 3.36/3.37/3.38 but the result is the same. Any idea?

Comment: How did you solve the problem with the API Key security? If I put the API key in GMMap it can be get by a network listener. In google console you can create a service account and get a token, but how to use it?

Comment: Perhaps some changes into the API need more params into the URL (or less)

Comment: Finally I found out that the API key was misconfigured and this caused the problem. I configured the API key properly and the component works correctly. Sorry for the fake alert.